# Is using PHP's `list` function considered bad practice?

Tags: php

Could not search for this topic due to **list** being a very common word.

```
list($total, $tax) = $this->getOrderAmounts();
```

Is this considered bad practice or code smell? I feel like I've been using it as a bad shortcut recently.

*Aside: `list` is actually a language construct, not a function*

Comment: I've never heard anyone bad mouthing list personally.

Comment: It's readable which makes it ok in my book. If you're looking to micro-optimize you may want to avoid it. But that's about it.

Comment: `Like array(), this is not really a function, but a language construct. list() is used to assign a list of variables in one operation.`

Comment: I don't like using it that way because without explicitly knowing what $this->getOrderAmounts() is going to return, or if the method changes, list() becomes arbitrary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally wouldn't use list because it is so "not precise". Consider this :-

```
$rainbow = array('violet', 'indigo','blue','green','yellow','orange','red');
list($violet,,,,,,$red) = $rainbow;

echo "$violet has low wavelength and $red has highest wavelength"; //Outputs violet has low wavelength and red has highest wavelength
```

But if you make a mistake :-

```
$rainbow = array('violet', 'indigo','blue','green','yellow','orange','red');
list($violet,,,,,$red) = $rainbow;

echo "$violet has low wavelength and $red has highest wavelength"; //violet has low wavelength and orange has highest wavelength
```

This would be so easier :-

```
$rainbow = array('violet', 'indigo','blue','green','yellow','orange','red');

echo "$rainbow[0] has low wavelength and $rainbow[6] has highest wavelength";
```

Comment: I wouldn't consider that a reason not to use list if I'm just using it for short arrays with no comma-skipping, as in list($a, $b) = ['x', 'y']; I find it useful to have a function return more than one variable (return ['x', 'y'];) and then getting the values with list($a, $b) = myPrivateFunctionWithTwoReturnValues(). What's wrong with that?

Comment: @Samosa, Hello, people often use list for 2 or 3 variables. What kind of odd example is this?